# What is a replacement for a deprecated JaCoCo extension in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I'm using `Robolectric` and `JaCoCo` together. My code coverage reports do not work without the following lines of code in gradle script:

```
 testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        jacoco {
            includeNoLocationClasses = true
        }
    }
 }
```

But in the recent version of Gradle the JaCoCo extension, that I use here, is marked as deprecated. I could not find any replacement for it. So, where should I apply the `includeNoLocationClasses = true` option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the Gradle Kotlin DSL with Gradle `5.5.1` and Kotlin `1.3.31` this works:

```
tasks {
    withType<Test> {
        configure<JacocoTaskExtension> {
            isIncludeNoLocationClasses = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed `excludes = listOf("jdk.internal.*")` as well as `isIncludeNoLocationClasses = true`.  Without the `excludes` I got a `NoClassDefFoundError` with `GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor1`.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. JaCoCo automatically adds `jacoco` extension to all tasks of `test` type. So, all that I had to do was adding the following lines into build script:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}
```

It doesn't look like an official solution, but it allows the custom `JacocoReport` implementation to work correctly.

Comment: Doesnt' work for me (Gradle 5.1.1 / Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1):

`Could not set unknown property 'includeNoLocationClasses' for object of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension.
`

Comment: I also get this error: 

Could not set unknown property 'includeNoLocationClasses' for object of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoPluginExtension.

Comment: My answer is outdated. See the recent solution above.